# Splitting ML model between classes

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a ML model where we're testing which genes are being driven by KRAS_variants. I've created a model based on 1000 variable genes with a 80/20 train vs test design.

```
set.seed(123)  # Set a seed for reproducibility
train_index <- createDataPartition(TCGA_data.sub.tpm.log$KRAS_status, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train_data <- TCGA_data.sub.tpm.log[train_index, ]
train_data[1:5, 1:5]
dim(train_data) # 142 19752
test_data <- TCGA_data.sub.tpm.log[-train_index, ]
test_data[1:5, 1:5]
dim(test_data) # 33 19752

# Calculate gene variances and select the top 1000 variable genes
gene_variances <- apply(train_data[, -ncol(train_data)], 2, var)
head(gene_variances)
#       OR4F5   FO538757.2   FO538757.1       OR4F29       OR4F16       SAMD11 
# 0.0000000000 0.0073489594 0.1823472021 0.0006655452 0.0006655452 0.4452401729 

top_variable_genes <- names(sort(gene_variances, decreasing = TRUE)[1:1001])
head(top_variable_genes) 
# [1] "CTRB2"  "CTRB1"  "CPA1"   "CELA3A" "PNLIP"  "CPB1" 
tail(top_variable_genes)
# [1] "CYBB"   "SLC7A2" "RGS4"   "FCGR2B" "MXRA8"  "ADAM8" 

# Remove "SERPINA3.1" from top_variable_genes (get error (Error in `[.data.frame`(train_data, , c(top_variable_genes, "KRAS_status")) :
# undefined columns selected))
top_variable_genes <- setdiff(top_variable_genes, "SERPINA3.1")

# Subset the data to include only the top 1000 variable genes
train_data <- train_data[, c(top_variable_genes, "KRAS_status")]
test_data <- test_data[, c(top_variable_genes, "KRAS_status")]

library(caret)

# Set a seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Define the parameter grid
param_grid <- expand.grid(
  mtry = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)        # Number of variables randomly selected at each split
)

# Create a custom train control with cross-validation
train_control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",              # Cross-validation
  number = 5,                 # Number of folds
  verboseIter = TRUE          # Show progress
)

# Train the random forest model with hyperparameter tuning
model_rf_tuned <- train(
  KRAS_status ~ .,            # Formula
  data = train_data,          # Training data
  method = "rf",              # Random forest method
  tuneGrid = param_grid,      # Parameter grid
  trControl = train_control  # Train control
)

# View the best hyperparameters and model results
print(model_rf_tuned)

# Make predictions on the test set using the tuned model
predictions <- predict(model_rf_tuned, newdata = test_data)

# Evaluate the tuned model's performance (e.g., confusion matrix)
confusion_matrix <- confusionMatrix(predictions, test_data$KRAS_status)
print(confusion_matrix)
```

Is there a way to split the results based on KRAS_status? For example list the specific genes per variant.